# Apache WSGIScriptAlias - skip a certain prefix

Tags: apache-2.2, alias, wsgi

The docs for WSGIScriptAliasMatch https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptAliasMatch are openly scary. Is there a way to say "Everything in this directory goes through this WSGI script, unless the URL begins with a tilde, in which case process it the old way"?

My site file is currently like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ... other directives ...
    AliasMatch ^/1/~(.*)$ /var/www/rosuav.com/1/~$1
    WSGIScriptAlias /1 /var/www/rosuav.com/1/1.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

In theory, it ought to be possible to have the WSGIScriptAlias directive specifically ignore URLs beginning with tildes, but I don't want to break stuff :)

Comment: To clarify, part of the key here is that I don't want to have to repeat the directory name everywhere. Especially if I end up with multiple alias negations, each having to repeat `/var/www/rosuav.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the tail end of the section:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

It explains how you can have access against a directory fallback to using an overlaying WSGI application if there is no static file mapping to the URL.

Stepping back though, can you explain the original problem rather than the solution you believe you need?

Is the issue that you are having problems with the precedence order between ~username directories supported by mod_userdir and WSGIScriptAlias from mod_wsgi?

This is a known issue but not had a recent complaint about it, so hasn't been fixed.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=224

---

UPDATE 1

Also read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html

This explains how to mix PHP and Python sites together.

Comment: The problem I'm looking at is this: I used to have a directory with a handful of PHP scripts, and a number of symlinks to other directories. I rewrote the PHP scripts' functionality in Python, using Flask and WSGI, but I want the symlinks to still be functional - that is, going to http://.../~whatever/something.php should still execute the PHP script, even though http://.../somepage will now be executed by Python.

Comment: I'm not using mod_userdir, btw; they're not user names per se, they're just symlinks that happen to begin with tildes. (They look like user names to the outside world, but aren't implemented that way.) The current system works, but doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: The recipe using AddHandler/RewriteRule in that doc should be able to be used then. Also read blog post have added link for above.